# does socket.io serving websockets need to physically be on port 80?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, haproxy

using `node.js` and `socket.io` to serve `websockets`

does `socket.io` need to be listening on port 80 - the real port for `websockets`, or can it be proxied to a different port, eg, port 8011, on the server?

the browser, using `websockets`, talks through 80/http.  on the server `haproxy`  redirects `websockets` to `node.js`.

right `haproxy` directs to `127.0.4.11:80`.  this works fine, but this requires `sudo` to run `node.js`.

would rather redirect to `localhost:8011`, but do not know if `socket.io` needs to actually be on port 80 to support `websockets` correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebSockets (and Socket.IO) can run on any port; most developers will develop their servers on a high-numbered port specifically to avoid running as root in development. Furthermore, the Socket.IO wiki has a [page on ports and which ones work for various firewall software](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Socket.IO-and-firewall-software).

Comment: but websockets over 80 is a different animal, requiring that complicated `http extend`(?) handshake, right?  if it uses 80 then firewalls are not an issue.  the question is whether socket.io, which is proxied, needs to know that, as far as the browser is concerned it's "really" on 80, to do its job correctly.

Comment: The answer to your last question is no. As long as the browser thinks it's on 80 (to avoid same-origin issues) it will work fine regardless of what port it's proxied to.